# Angular 7 popover loading

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, fabricjs, popover

I am using fabricjs to load image and textcontents.

I have many textcontents on canvas with fabricjs.

now on click of textcontents of fabricjs I want to open Angular 7 popover may be (ngbPopover).

how to open that on click of textcontents, like we are opening dialogbox?

because I can not inject popover config anywhere in fabricjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was trying to say something like this, And I found solution here.

```
const showImageTools = (e) => {
                                    const content = '<div id="imageDialog" class="container">\n' +
                                        '        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">\n' +
                                        '            <input value="' + pngText.texts + '" id="textInputField" style="width: 400px;\n' +
                                        '    box-shadow: 2px 4px 5px 3px #bdc3bdee;height: 50px;\n' +
                                        '    padding: 5px;\n' +
                                        '    border-radius: 5px;" matInput placeholder="Add your texts"/>\n' +
                                        '        </mat-form-field>\n' +
                                        '    </div>';
                                    $("body").append(content);
                                    moveImageTools();
                                };

                                this.canvas.add(pngText).renderAll();
                                pngText.on('mousedown', event => {
                                    showImageTools(event);
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar functionality to do but I found another shortcut way in doing it so.

- On click of the text, object read the object by using

  > this.canvas.on('object:selected', (e) => {this.objectSelected(e)});
- Then initally makesure that the textbox/popover is hidden
- On click of the object read the selected object by:

  > var absCoords = this.canvas.getActiveObject();
- When you read the active object there are things that you will have to take care

  - unhide the textbox/popover
  - get `absCoords.left` and `absCoords.top` and set it to the textbox.

This is one of the workarounds which helped to solve it.